# Android - how to set an ArrayList ListView with a field from an object but also track the items id

Tags: android

I declare this adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<Problem> adapter;
```

I also declare this this ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Problem> problems = new ArrayList <Problem>( );
```

My Problem class has only 2 fields: problemId and problemName.

I make a call to remote db and populate the data like this:

```
                    for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                    {
                        JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);                                

                        problem_title = o.getString("problem_title");
                        problem_id = o.getString("problem_id");

                        Problem p = new Problem ( );
                        p.setProblemId(problem_id);                         
                        p.setProblemId(problem_title);

                        problems.add( p );                                                      
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So the stuff that gets displayed to the screen is object reference, but what I want displayed is  the name, and when a user clicks that item, I should also be able to retrieve the id of that item in my listener here:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) 
    {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (( TextView ) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      // For now just do something simple like display a responsive message
      Log.d( "MyProblemsActivity" , "A choice was made from the list: " + (( TextView ) view).getText() );
      Log.d( "MyProblemsActivity" , "position: " + position );
      Log.d( "MyProblemsActivity" , "id: " + id );

    }
  });
```

Help is much appreciated!!!!

Thanks!

Comment: The "question" in this question cannot easily be deciphered.  What exactly do you need help with?  It seems like you already have some working code, and the title of your question doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @synic right now the object reference gets displayed on the screen. I need just the problemName to get displayed on the screen, but a referring id to be saved to be used later. Does that help to make the question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just need to Override th toString() method of your Problem object. Something like

```
public String toString() {
    return problemName;
}
```

This is the default text an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) will use to fill the TextView.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I'm clear on the question, but maybe this helps...

You can store a piece of data with any GUI element (View) in Android by using the tag.

Here is the View::setTag function:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

"... Tags can also be used to store data within a view without resorting to another data structure."